# Shopping cart and payment method section in backend are blank

Tags: magento2

So this is my shopping cart and the payment method section where you would be able to configure your methods is also blank. So far we have been unable to figure out why this is happening and all fixes do not work. HELP HELP HELP

Comment: Have you checked logs.

Comment: I did check the logs doesnt seem to be anything in there causing the issue.